# Proof of Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm in the middle of a multi-step problem which seeks to figure out, given a box of $k+1$ coins each of which has equal probability of being chosen for flipping, and each of which has a probability of heads $=\frac{i}{k}$, for $i=1,2,...,k$, and given that the first $n$ flips have been heads, what is the probability that the next $m$ flips will also be heads.

Right now, I have $A_i$ denoting the event that the $i$th coin is selected, $E$ the event that the first $n$ flips were heads. I have also defined $M$ as the event that the next $m$ flips after the first $n$ will also be heads. I need to prove that:

$$P(M|E)=\sum_{i=0}^kP(M|A_i\cap E)P(A_i|E)$$

I know that if $A_i$ are events that form a partition in a space $\Omega$, and if $E$ is an event, then we have:

$$P(E)=\sum_{i=0}^nP(E|A_i)(P(A_i))$$

I have tried plugging in $M|E$ into this, which yields:

$$P(M|E)=\sum_{i=0}^kP((M|E)|A_i)P(A_i)$$

Using the fact that $(A|B)|C=A|B\cap C$, we get:

$$P(M|E)=\sum_{i=0}^kP(M| E\cap A_i)P(A_i)$$

However, I can't seem to fix the probability on the end of the RHS. Perhaps I'm plugging in my values incorrectly into the theorem, but I can't convince myself why what I am doing is incorrect. Any suggestions would be helpful. Cheers.

Comment: I'm missing something.  you say there are $k+1$ coins, but you only seem to give $k$ probabilities.

Comment: I agree that it seems odd, but that's the way it was phrased. After some more research, I found virtually identical problem (one which asks what the probability is of the n+1 flip being heads: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55189425e4b017e0133cc3c2/t/56119b59e4b02dbd234423d2/1443994457854/Chapter_3_MATH305_Lecture_Notes.pdf
The rest of the question is identical to my problem. I've been going through this to understand the methodology. For reference, the problem in the link is 5(e).